# Consuming XML-RPC in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, xml-rpc

I'm trying to consume XML-RPC in React Native using [mimic](http://mimic-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/) javascript library

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

const xmlrpc = require('./mimic');

class TestXmlRpc extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        var request = new xmlrpc.XmlRpcRequest("http://192.168.43.10:8000", 'add');  
        request.addParam(1);  
        request.addParam(3);  
        var response = request.send();  
        console.log(response.parseXML()); 
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestXmlRpc', () => TestXmlRpc);
```

but I keep getting the error 'Synchronous http requests are not supported'
what am I doing wrong? thx a lot

Comment: Anyone have anything on this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to change such calls

```
xhr.open("POST", this.serviceUrl, false);
```

into

```
xhr.open("POST", this.serviceUrl, true);
```

since async is required now